# How could I add a delay in processing failed messages in ServiceStack Redis MQ

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis, redismqserver

Is there an easy way to get Servicestack to wait x seconds before retrying a failed MQ item (using Redis MQ). At the moment it just tries 3 times consecutively with no delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register a MQ handler you can also register an error handler which gets called after publishing a failed message which you can use to add a custom delay, e.g:

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<MyRequest>(
    ServiceController.ExecuteMessage,
    (msgHandler, msg, ex) => Thread.Sleep(1000));
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear. The error handler finishes executing before the message gets retried/reposted to the queue?

Comment: @richardwhatever it's fired after the error response is published, but can be used to delay that worker handler thread before it executes its next message.

Comment: @mythz the solution you provided using Thread.Sleep can work but this is not durable, (i.e. in the case of system failure during 1 second wait). Is there anyway to not use a Thread.Sleep and chuck the failed msg back to the redis queue and somehow handle this msg later (i.e. don't dequeue until say 2 secs later). Maybe ZRANGE can help?

Comment: @mythz actually, maybe I need to use DLQ to handle proper delayed retry. Instead of relying on SS to handle it for me. But NServiceBus does have it baked in.